# QtCreator's code completion doesn't work for Qt libs

Tags: qt, autocomplete, qt-creator

When trying to work in QtCreator, there is a problem with code completion for Qt libs. QtCreator says that it can't find Qt headers, so no code completion for them. I.e. if I write `#include <QPainter>` or `#include <QtGui/QPainter>` this line gets underlined with message `No such file or directory`.

But nevertheless compilation process works flawlessly. So, `qmake` finds everything correctly and the problem is in the QtCreator. Also, code completion works normally for all own files (created for project).

We've tried numerous fixes including reinstalling Qt twice, trying to mangle with `qt.conf` in QtCreator's dir, tried to find `qmake.cache`, searching the registry and googled a lot. We're using QtSdk 1.1 with bundled QtCreator 2.2.1 under Windows Vista, installed in the default location.

There is dirty solution to write path in `.pro` file, but we don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose one of the following files

> **Qt_install**/mkspecs/common/**your_os**.conf

or

> **Qt_install**/mkspecs/common/**your_compiler**.conf

By Qt_install I mean the directory where Qt is installed (not qt creator), e.g. C:\Qt\Qt 4.7.4\ and your_compiler should be mingw I guess (don't have a windows install).

In the .conf file, add the line with the path you added in your .pro, something like:

> INCLUDEPATH += path1 path2 ...

The mkspecs files are implicitly included in all your .pro so code completion will work in all your projects.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Can't test it though as I have no access to  notebook in question at the moment.